# Rails 3 - Validating Forms with Only One Set of Radio Buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

As a beginning Ruby on Rails 3 developer, I'm looking for recommendations on how best to validate a form with just one set of radio buttons. This particular form is part of a web app with multiple forms - my controller to direct the flow to different forms depending on the answer selected.

My html.erb snippet:

```
<%= form_for @selection do |f| %>
<%= f.error_messages %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.radio_button :answer, 'Y' %>
  <%= f.label :answer, 'Y' %>
  <br/>
  <%= f.radio_button :answer, 'N' %>
  <%= f.label :answer, 'N' %>
</div>

<div class="action">
  <%= submit_tag 'Save', :name => 'save_button' %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Continue', :name => 'submit' %>
</div>
```

<% end %>

Selection.rb (model):

```
require 'active_model'

class Selection
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :answer

  validates_presence_of :answer

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

With only one form element other than the submit buttons, I received a nil error when I didn't select one of the radio buttons. I was able to get the validation to work properly when I did one of two things - add another field to the form and model or set a default value:

```
@selection = Selection.new(:answer => "N")
```

I elected to go with the default value solution, which did away with any need for validation, but was wondering if there was a better way of setting up my app if my users did not want a pre-selected answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may depend on what you want it to do.

You might check for the nil yourself, and when nil, redirect back to the form with an error message in flash[:error].

Answer (score 0):

**Working Solution**
As Marlin suggested, I checked for null and then passed in a flash[:error] message.

*Controller snippet*

```
if params[:answer].nil?
  flash[:error] = "Please make a selection"
  redirect_to selections_path
end
```

*View snippet*

```
<% unless flash[:error].blank? %>
    <div id="notification_error"><%= flash[:error] %></div>
<% end %>
```